# Access paypal account through email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, stripe-payments

Let me explain my site(ruby on Rails) current scenario:

1) We can create multiple admin account from my website.

2) Each admin has their own customers and these customers also have their site access section.

3) Each customer can submit some payment to their related admin paypal account.

4) And this submitted amount should be transffer to admin paypal account.

Problem:

we want access admin Paypal account through their email address and we don't want to define an interface where user/admin can submit their account credentials like merchant key etc.

Is there any option through I can achieve this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve it with using [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), creating payments between users and using other calls requires only users' emails.

To get exact email that user has specified on PayPal you can use [Log In with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/log-in-with-paypal/detailed/) feature, it allows you to get basic info about user through OAuth protocol. This way is more reliable than manual email input by users.